# Obter o Resumo dos resultados a partir da utilização do LOESS

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber como posso obter os pontos que são gerados por minha curva. Estou com dificuldade de obter os resultados da minha última instrução do código.

Além disso, eu obtive os pontos máximos e mínimos da curva, mas gostaria também de obter o primeiro ponto e o último da curva. Tem como obter o primeiro e ultimo ponto da minha curva?

Tentei usar alguns conceitos como head ou summary, mas não funcionam para minha última instrução. Meu código é o seguinte:

```
 plot(dados.frame)
 dados.loess <- loess(duracao ~date_time, data=dados.frame)
 xl <- with(dados.frame, seq(min(date_time),max(date_time), (max(date_time) - min(date_time))/1000))
 y.predict <- predict(dados.loess, xl)
 lines(xl,y.predict)
 infl <- c(FALSE, diff(diff(y.predict)>0)!=0)
 points(xl[infl ], y.predict[infl ], col="Red", pch=19, cex=1.25)
```

Como resultado eu tenho:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigada!!! As duas respostas me ajudaram muito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fica mais fácil de responder explicando cada um dos seus comandos:

o comando:

```
xl <- with(dados.frame, seq(min(date_time),max(date_time), (max(date_time) - min(date_time))/1000))
```

cria uma sequêcia com todas as datas entre a data mínima e a data máxima que você possuia no seu banco de dados.

em seguida:

```
y.predict <- predict(dados.loess, xl)
```

cria o valor predito da duração, de acordo com cada data que foi definida em `xl`.

Neste ponto você já poderia salvar um arquivo com data e duração predita fazendo:

```
cbind(xl, y.predict)
```

Os próximos comandos procuram os pontos de inflexão. O comando a seguir cria um vetor de TRUE ou FALSE. TRUE indicando que o ponto é de inflexão.

```
infl <- c(FALSE, diff(diff(y.predict)>0)!=0)
```

Portanto se vc fizer

```
cbind(xl, y.predict)[infl,]
```

Obterá apenas as linhas que possuem os pontos de inflexão.

Para obter o primeiro e o último ponto da curva, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

`cbind(xl, y.predict)[xl == min(xl),]` e `cbind(xl, y.predict)[xl == max(xl),]`

Comment: Obrigada, Daniel. Você me ajudou muito com seus esclarecimentos.

Answer (score 0):

Tem que postar um código reproduzível. Pode tentar:

```
cbind(xl,y.predict) # a curva
cbind(xl[infl ], y.predict[infl ])  # os pontos max/min
```

Comment: Obrigada, Robert! Também funcionou dessa forma.